# Library that includes Unmodifiable extensions of  java.util.Properties, sql.Date, util.Date, etc

Tags: java

Firstly let me say I believe immutability is one of the best things one can do to improve the reliability, simplicity and give one confidence about a system. No more worries about defensive copies or values changing and so on which is for me a good thing.

That said though simple the Collections library unmodifiableXXX methods are a simple way to present readonly collections which is a good thing and keeps stuff safe. It doesn't solve all problems in the universe but its a good thing to have.

After all that I am after a library that tries to fix some of the other warts.

**A read only properties**

- the r/o would wrap another Properties
- extends java.util.Properties
- mutator methods throw UOE.
- keySet/valueSet views etc should also be read only

**mutable properties**

- the map (e.g. put) methods throw UOE
- only the proper Properties methods like setProperty should work.
- extends java.util.Properties

The exercise for Properties is repeated for Stack as well. Repeat exercise for java.util.Date, java.sql.Date etc.

Please don't tell me to write my own, because yes I could but I was hoping this boring stuff was already done :)

Comment: I can see having an extension of Properties, but I think that if you want to pass along values that don't change you should pass `long` values returned by getTime(). The `long` values are cheap and unlike Objects (Date is an object) they get copied because they are so cheap.

Comment: I agree w/ you, but unfortunately many third party APIs take Properties, Dates which i cannot change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such a library exists.

However, I won't tell you to write your own because I think it would be a waste of time:

- For the `java.util.Date` case, use the Joda time APIs in which the basic date / time objects are immutable.
- For the immutable `Properties` case, wrap the `Properties` object in an unmodifiable `Map`.
- For the mutable `Properties` case, use `HashMap<String, String>` instead of `Properties`.
- The `java.sql.Date` case is impractical to solve because of the JDBC methods that *return* `java.sql.Date` instances.

---

Consider this.  Millions of Java programmers have gotten by for years *without* having readonly versions of these util classes.  Apparently nobody has thought it worth their while to create / publish such a library.  Does this tell you something?  Maybe, that this is not a real problem?  Or that there are better solutions (like Joda time).

For instance, when I write a method that pass a Properties object to some method, I take a look at the API of the method.  Does it say or imply that it modifies / might modify the object?  Do I care?  Unless the answer is that "yes" to both of these, I don't *need* to make a defensive copy.  If the answer to both is "yes", then I do need to make a defensive copy ... and an immutable object is not the answer.

Now if Java was being redesigned from the ground up starting today, then a better way of dealing with mutable versus immutable objects would be high on *my* agenda.  But it ain't.

But hey, you are free to disagree with me and implement your own library.

Comment: Everyone loves your Jodatime :) thanx for that and your other Joda stuff. My request only exists because many third party libs etc take Properites, Dates which i cant change. True sql.Date might be problematic but there are a few APIs that TAKE Timestamp etc.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could always call `clone` on an object.

But if you **really want a readonly Properties** it is really easy to extend an object if you use an IDE like NetBeans. I could do it in 10 minutes. Iterators and all. If you do not use an IDE, I suggest you learn either NetBeans or Eclipse which are the two most common. I use NetBeans.

If you use Eclipse, The only thing I don't know is if you can create delegate methods in Eclipse.

Here are the instructions for NetBeans.

1. Create a class and extend Properties. Make one private variable called `private final Properties backend;`
2. Make a constructor `public MyProperties(Properties backend){this.backend=backend;}`
3. Move your cursor to right after the constructor, and Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. Choose background as what you are delegating to and check all the methods and continue.
4. For the methods that you do not want to work, you just paste in `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unmodifiable Properties");`
5. keySet and valueSet just have to return unmodifiable wrappers of what they are returning now (as of step 4).