# Why does Javac generate different classes for each Enum literal

Tags: java, enums

Firstly my comment relates to simple enums that do not include their own individual methods. I cant think of any tehcnical reason and it seems quite wasteful to create soo many little classes when the main would be enuff.

```
DaysOfWeekEnum {
  MON,//
  TUES, //
}
```

@Aman Thanks for pointing out my mistake, i must have made a mistake looking at my output dir. I will close when i can.

Comment: Because that way the VM specification can remain the same (as before enums were added tot the language), only the language specification changes?

Comment: Congratulations, you have over 200 questions without an accepted answer. :P

Comment: @PeterLawrey , I'd like to upvote your comment but I could flag it as "not constructive" as well :-P. So, I'll resist doing either and get flagged myself probably...

Comment: @JohannesWeiß Check a few of my unanswered, they are fair q, that really have not been answered. Unfortunately SO is full of boring questions with simple answers for them.

Comment: @martijno Creating the inner classes solves no problem. The variant stuff like name could simply be a field on the outter class which is set by the ctor.

Comment: Well firstly, its only 110 questions without an accepted answer, not 200 as I miscalculated. Picking one at random ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361826/library-that-includes-unmodifiable-extensions-of-java-util-properties-sql-date Stephens reply that "none exists" seems reasonable given no one has added an answer in over a year.

Comment: Can you explain what resource is being wasted and how much this is costing? e.g. in $. I can name time as a valuable resource that could be wasted otherwise. ;)

Comment: Hey I tried it and it does not create new class file for each "constant" it only creates a new one for enum declared. pls check through again.

Comment: @Aman Sorry your right i withdraw the q. I must have made a mistake looking at the output dir.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i have closed that q. Thanks for point that one out, now try another rather than cherry picking :().

Comment: @mP. I would suggest you go through all the unaccepted questions again, not with a eye for whether you liked the answer but whether its the best answer anyone was able to give. For the questions where you got no answer, I would try to learn from that and see how you can avoid asking such answers in future.

Comment: @mP. Not sure what you mean by "simply a field on the outer class". What type would that field have, and how do you guarantee type-safety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a misake asking this q. ignore it its wrong!!!

Answer (score 1):

An enum does have methods, even if you do not declare them. Each enum overrides methods from  `java.lang.Enum` to give reasonable implementations of the enum specific methods, and javac generates a `valueOf` method specific to that enum. Is also seems silly to have to recompile all classes that use an enum when the first user method is added to the enum.

Comment: the sythentic methods live on the outter class. Im talking about the inner classes.

Comment: @mP: You misunderstand me. If you create an enum `E` then javac will generate: public class E { public static E valueOf(String s) {...} ...} and not an empty class...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Jar, only one file is created.

The fact that you can index more of the entries is a plus as it allows them to be lazy loaded with finer granularity.

IMHO, nothing would be gained by having less `.class` files

> it seems quite wasteful

Cost of 10,000 small files you don't need assuming it wastes 5 MB: 0.022 cents.

How much of your time is worth 0.022 cents assuming you are on minimum wage: 11 seconds.

If you spend more than 11 seconds trying to save 10,000 files, it could be wasteful.

Comment: @NathanHughes i Dont care about disk space, my q is purely theoretical. The way it is seems wrong.

Comment: @mP: i didn't answer your question, Peter Lawrey did, I just edited the answer to fix a typo. Nobody will want to answer your questions if you downvote everybody.

Comment: Theoretically anything is possible and its only reality which forces us to make concrete choices. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory

Comment: For me it seem wrong to spend $10 to save $0.0002. It seems wrong even in theory. ;)

Comment: In one country, Opera and Ballet were made illegal on the basis that they were pointless.  The ruler clearly felt they were wrong things to be wasting your time one.  While some people might not see the point of ballet or opera, it appears to be strange to me to be worrying about such things which is likely to be more wasteful than it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in line : All enums implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum.`

Comment: You missed the point. Create a simple Enum as included in the q and you see inner classes for each "constant".

Comment: @mP. Hey I tried it and it does not create new class file for each "constant" it only creates a new one for enum declared. pls check through again.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of an enum is creating a type with a finite number of values. The only way to do this in Java - *with minor changes to the language* - is generating a class for the enum, generating the values as constant objects of that class, and making sure noone can instantiate other objects of that class.